# Why does the regex not capture the initial word? Python

Tags: python, regex

Why does my regex pattern not capture the word before the preposition?

My regex pattern is trying to capture Proper Nouns that have prepositions after them.
For instance:
• Academy of Management --> Academy of
• McGraw Hill Foundation of Books --> Foundation of

For the following text:

> 'The Academy of Management Entrepreneurship Division and McGraw Hill present the annual award to individuals who develop and implement an innovation in entrepreneurship pedagogy for either graduate or undergraduate education.'

```
pp = r'[A-Z][A-Za-z]+\s+\b(for|of|in|by)\b(?=\s+[A-Z][A-Za-z]+)'

x2 = re.findall(pp,test)
```

`x2`

outputs:

'of'

Why doesn't it output 'Academy of'?

Comment: What exactly is your regex trying to capture? I speak a little regex, but I'm more fluent in English.

Comment: You haven't put a `(capture)` around the first part.

Comment: @TomFenech Hey Tom, that is helpful. Can you explain a little bit more about why that's needed? I realized capturing groups wasn't something I never quite understood. If you write an explanation in the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A capturing group is a section of a regular expression enclosed in parentheses `( )`. They are used to extract specific sections from a matching expression. It looks like you've encountered them by chance, as you're using one to match "for", "of", "in" or "by".

When you have one capturing group in your expression (as in your question), `re.findall` will return a list of matches for that group. At the moment, you don't have any group around the first part of your regular expression. If you want to capture it as well, you must also enclose it in some parentheses:

```
pp=r'([A-Z][A-Za-z]+\s+\b(for|of|in|by))\b(?=\s+[A-Z][A-Za-z]+)'
#    ^                                 ^
re.findall(pp,test)
```

returns:

```
[('Academy of', 'of')]
```

Now `re.findall` has returned a list of tuples because there are now multiple capturing groups. The elements of the tuple appear in the order that the groups begin.

If you don't want to also match the other group, you can change it to be non-capturing:

```
(?:for|of|in|by)
```

Then the only thing that will be captured is `['Academy of']`. Although now you're left with only one capture group, so you can dispense with the parentheses entirely and `re.findall` will return anything matching the full regular expression.

```
pp=r'[A-Z][A-Za-z]+\s+\b(?:for|of|in|by)\b(?=\s+[A-Z][A-Za-z]+)'
```

Answer (score 3):

Just put a capture group for the word before the preposition:

`pp = r'([A-Z][A-Za-z]+)\s+\b(for|of|in|by)\b(?=\s+[A-Z][A-Za-z]+)'`

Or if you want to capture the whole word/preposition string:

`pp = r'([A-Z][A-Za-z]+\s+\b(?:for|of|in|by))\b(?=\s+[A-Z][A-Za-z]+)'`

Comment: -0.  Now you have captured two groups.  From the question we can see the OP wants to capture the preposition and the preceding word as a single group.

Comment: Ok, then `pp =r'([A-Z][A-Za-z]+\s+\b(?:for|of|in|by))\b(?=\s+[A-Z][A-Za-z]+)'`

Answer (score 2):

The actual regex search is working as you'd expect. What's tripping you up is the fact that there's a capture group introduced by the parentheses around `for|of|in|by`.

From the `re.findall()` [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups.

Here is how you can fix this:

```
pp = r'[A-Z][A-Za-z]+\s+\b(?:for|of|in|by)\b(?=\s+[A-Z][A-Za-z]+)'
                           ^^
```

The `(?:...)` is a [non-capture group](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). With this, `re.findall()` will return the entire match.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

In the case of your pattern, you have one capturing group `(for|of|in|by)` and one non-capturing group `(?=\s+[A-Z][A-Za-z]+)` (non-capturing because of the question mark).

If you want to return 'Academy of' as  single string, just make the capturing group non-capturing:

```
pp = r'[A-Z][A-Za-z]+\s+\b(?:for|of|in|by)\b(?=\s+[A-Z][A-Za-z]+)'
                           ^
re.findall(pp,test) # prints ['Academy of']
```

Comment: -0.  This is merely a reword of NPE's answer.  It adds nothing and it's posted 2 minutes later.